openstack-helm neutron install and host route error
guide：
https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-helm/latest/install/openstack.html#compute-kit-placement-nova-neutron
config and command：
PROVIDER_INTERFACE=<provider_interface_name>
tee ${OVERRIDES_DIR}/neutron/values_overrides/neutron_simple.yaml << EOF
conf:
  neutron:
    DEFAULT:
      l3_ha: False
      max_l3_agents_per_router: 1
  # <provider_interface_name> will be attached to the br-ex bridge.
  # The IP assigned to the interface will be moved to the bridge.
  auto_bridge_add:
    br-ex: ${PROVIDER_INTERFACE}
  plugins:
    ml2_conf:
      ml2_type_flat:
        flat_networks: public
    openvswitch_agent:
      ovs:
        bridge_mappings: public:br-ex
EOF

helm upgrade --install neutron openstack-helm/neutron \
    --namespace=openstack \
    $(helm osh get-values-overrides -p ${OVERRIDES_DIR} -c neutron neutron_simple ${FEATURES})

my host route before：
default via 192.168.3.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 100
192.168.3.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.107 metric 100

after run command：
default via 192.168.3.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 100
192.168.3.0/24 dev br-ex proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.107
192.168.3.1 dev eno1 proto static scope link metric 100
192.168.50.0/24 dev virbr1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.1
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1

can not connect to public network
give me solution，how to change the config
